# Android installer installs 2 instances?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, icons, apk

The problem I have is that whenever I export my appto an apk, and then install on device, or debug in eclipse, 2 instances of my app is installed(?). 2 icons are added to my menu.

How do I stop that from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the activity intent set as  in the AndroidManifest.xml

Removing this resolved the problem

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question, saved me some time ;)